# Mongodb 2dsphere: "$err" : "can't find special index: 2d for

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geojson

In my mongodb Collection I have a 2dsphere index

```
{ "ns" : "PanPanDB.posts", "key" : { "location_2dsphere" : "2dsphere" }, "name" : "location_2dsphere_2dsphere", "background" : true, "safe" : null, "unique" : false }
```

When I query on it I obtain the following error:

```
> db.posts.find( { "location_2dsphere" :{ $near : {$geometry:    { type : "Point" , coordinates : [ 100 , 5 ] } , $maxDistance : 1000}}}  )
error: {
    "$err" : "can't find special index: 2d for: { location_2dsphere: { $near: { $geometry: { type: \"Point\", coordinates: { 0: 100.0, 1: 5.0 } }, $maxDistance: 1000.0 } } }"
}
```

Can you help me? There isn't much documentation on the web!

Comment: try specifying the index with db.posts.find(...).hint("location_2dsphere_2dsphere")  Do you get the same error?

Comment: I didn't get the error using your query in my MongoDB(v2.4.5). check the index again using "db.posts.getIndexes()"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using ubuntu, the default apt-get install mongodb-server gives you version 2.2 of mongodb which does not support 2dsphere indexes.

You may want to considering upgrading to 2.4: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thank you. Because Ubuntu tries to be quite bleeding edge, in Debian terms, I sometimes forget that many of its packages are a bit out of date -- and you wrote this over 8 months ago. The "can't find special index ... " was driving me mad.